# Адаптивное масштабирование блока между двумя блоками

Tags: css

Есть верхняя панель с топ: 0;
Есть нижняя панель с боттом: 0;

И есть блок между ними и там артинка стоит.

Проблема: при изменении высоты окна браузера этот самый блок, картинка, высота которого дана в процентах, смещается, падая на нижнюю панель и со временем прикрывает ее.

Вопрос: как сделать тобы сохранить пропорции. Чтобы средний блок сохранял свои пропорции при изменении высоты окна и не проглатывала нижнюю панель?

Comment: закиньте пример на jsFiddle

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/Rgk5x/ вот. Картинку сами поставите

Comment: @navi1893, поставьте картинку сами, почему что-то кто-то за вас будет делать ? есть же хостинг тестовых картинок. http://placehold.it/